Is $T(n) = 3 \cdot T(n/5) + 9n$ only defined for multiples of $5$?
If someone gives me the recurrence $T(n) = 3
\cdot T(n/5) + 9n$, would it only be defined for $n$ which is a multiple of $5$?
My CS course, when giving me recurrences whose asymptotic bound I am supposed to analyze, gives them to me in this fashion- I am confused because when given a recurrence like this, it says it has a certain $\Theta$ bound; yet my course only defines what it means for a function which maps from the positive integers to have a $\Theta$ bound, which makes it seems as if a recurrence such as the one above maps from the positive integers. Also, no base case is given which also confuses me (probably because it ends up not being useful for the asymptotic bound). However, I just wanted to clarify whether the above recurrence can be defined on the entire integers or not (assuming that it has an appropriate base case).

CS courses use recursions like this sloppily. Usually safe to treat $n/5$ as $\lceil n/5\rceil.$

@ThomasAndrews would it actually be that $/$ refers to integer division? So it is floor division? I think this is why they use this symbol instead of \frac, cuz in Programming languages it means integer division

Not really floor, no, ceiling. This is used when $T$ computes the estimated amount of time needed by an algorithm, given an input of size $n.$ The assumption is that $T$ is increasing. So $n/5$ will come up when you divide the problem into $5$ parts, so if $n/5$ is not an integer, some of those parts will be greater than $n/5,$ and the floor will underestimate the time, We usually worry about worst cases/upper bounds for the algorithm's time.

Also need to define the exact value for some $n$, if for example $T(1)=1$ then the $T(5)=48$, but if we set $T(\pi)=1$ then $T(5\pi)=3+9\pi$. So no multiplies of $5$.

It's even worse — if only $T(1)$ is given as a base case, then $T$ is only defined by the recurrence for powers of $5$.
In computer science the complexity is usually (but not always!) monotone, which allows us to derive an asymptotic result $T(n) = \Theta(n)$ for all $n$.
Some books spell this out, some just handwave.

Here is a method for reducing this to a homogeneous second-order difference equation. To keep things as general as possible, let's consider the recurrence relation
$$
T(n)=pT\bigg(\frac{n}{c}\bigg)+qn
$$
Let $n=c^k$, so that
$$
T(c^k)=pT\bigg(c^{k-1}\bigg)+qc^k
$$
Now, let $f(k)=T(c^k)$, so that we get the inhomogeneous first-order equation
$$
f(k)=pf(k-1)+qc^k
$$
This can be converted to a homogeneous second-order equation as follows. Consider
$$
\frac{f(k)-pf(k-1)}{f(k-1)-pf(k-2)}=\frac{qc^k}{qc^{k-1}}=c
$$
Or
$$
f(k)=af(k-1)+bf(k-2)\\
a=p+c,\quad b=-p
$$
with characteristic roots
$$
\alpha,\beta=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}=p,c
$$
Can you take it from here?
